# Frame displaying twice

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm facing a browser issue with my ASP.Net application. When I ran my application, some of the browsers are displaying my home page twice in the same page vertically.

This is the code im uisng in my aspx page, in my home.aspx page.

```
<frameset rows="121,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="5" framespacing="0" bordercolor="#999999"runat="server">
  <frame src="TopHeader.aspx" name="topFrame" scrolling="no"  noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frameset rows="*" cols="253,*" framespacing="5" frameborder="yes" border="1"  bordercolor="#e5e5e5" >
    <frame src="LeftNav.aspx" name="leftFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no"  id="leftFrame" title="leftFrame" runat="server" />
    <frame src="Default.aspx" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" frameborder="no" runat="server" />
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: frames? the 1990s called and want their HTML 3 back.

Comment: @Marc: i dint get u sir.

Answer (score 0):

I gone through your code, there you wrote frameborder="no" and border="5" those two may cause the effect. if border="5" then use frameborder="yes" and frameborder="0" will work instead of "no" 
Use cols="30%,70%" instead of cols="*" because the cols="*" will occupy all the available space.
I have run your code in my system and did not get page multiple times.

Comment: thank you for ur answer. i have tried in this way but it is not solving my prob